# Can we ask for academic advice,knowledge assessment on here or will it get closed

Tags: discussion

I am a computer science student and i'm interested to ask for advice on what to learn in my free time,things that all programmers/computer science graduates should know. I am intending to write a thorough question,so i don't want to put an effort into it and then see it closed. 
If i can't ask such a question here,where can i ?

Comment: Read the [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) documentation.  Every Stack Exchange site has an article detailing what is and is not on topic.

Comment: "advice on what to learn in my free time", "things that all programmers/computer science graduates should know" - both questions will most likely be closed and heavily voted down

Comment: You've got enough rep to ask in [chat] though.

Comment: These are important questions that most of us have asked ourselves at some point (I've asked myself 'what to learn in my free time' more than once), but they are still very broad. For example, my answer would likely be go as far as you can on your own in math, and then study patterns. But whos' to say you need to go further in math? What languages and patterns will help in your current studies rather than confuse you or even mislead you in the opinions of your current instructors?